# bigmemory package in R.3.0

Tags: r

I was using attach.big.matrix from bigmemory package in R.2.15.3 and it was working fine. By fine, I mean it attaches the matrix in reasonable time (less than 1 min). I upgraded R to 3.0.1 and now attachment is taking too long (more than hour to attach the same matrix. Anyone has any clue how to deal with this?

I could not downgrade R to R.2.15.3 due to lack of instructions. Any answer to either of the questions is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You really need to show the code that you say now doesn't work. If you can create a reproducible example you'll demonstrate clearly to us (and yourself) that it's a problem caused by versions.

Answer (score 0):

In R there's no automatic upgrade/downgrade. You can download previous versions of R from one of the CRAN mirrors (start [here](http://www.r-project.org/) and keep looking for previous releases). As an aside, check the package description file to see what version of R it was built under. It seems as well that if you're in Windows there could be potential issues with that package per the latest NEWS bulletin on the CRAN package page [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/NEWS). You could also try the package [ff](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html).